# Mule logger throws UnableToInferOutputTypeException

Tags: mule

I'm using a Mule 4 logger component in a flow to log two flow variables, var1 and var2. Both vars are strings.

```
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message='#["var1 = $(vars.var1), var2 = $(vars.var2)"]'/>
```

At runtime, this is throwing an exception:

```
Message : "org.mule.weave.v2.el.exceptions.UnableToInferOutputTypeException: Unable to infer a output media type as more than one is being used: application/java,application/json please specify using: 'output <your mime-type> --- <expr>'
```

Comment: The question misses reproduction information.

Comment: Why not use string concatenation instead of interpolation?

Comment: @aled It makes no difference whether you use concatenation or interpolation - you get the same error.

Comment: Questions should  still have reproduction steps, including example data.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the two vars having different MIME types – one is application/java and the other is application/json. The fix is to explicitly set the output type in the message:

```
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message='#[output application/java --- "var1 = $(vars.var1), var2 = $(vars.var2)"]'/>
```